# Problema con crear un ejecutable

Tags: python, pyinstaller, qt-designer

he creado una aplicación en python mediante QtDesigner, donde tengo varias ventanas separadas en carpetas. Cuando inicio la aplicación desde la terminal, inicia y funciona todas las opciones creadas, sin embargo, cuando utilizo el `pyinstaller` y logro convertir la ventana principal en ejecutable solo me abre el cmd por un segundo y se cierra sin abrir la aplicación, también intente colocarlo en un solo archivo con el `pyinstaller --onefile` y salió `Failed to execute Script`. Envió mi código de mi primera ventana para saber cual es el problema. Gracias!:

```
    import sys
    import os
    myDir = os.getcwd()
    sys.path.append(myDir)


    from Controllers.LoginController import LoginController
    from Views.principal import Ui_Principal
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_LogIn(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.login_controller = LoginController(self)

def setupUi(self, LogIn):
    LogIn.setObjectName("LogIn")
    LogIn.resize(871, 577)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(LogIn)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 60, 341, 161))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(28)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.label.setFont(font)
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 260, 161, 91))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(20)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.label_2.setFont(font)
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    self.btn_login = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.btn_login.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 450, 211, 61))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(20)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.btn_login.setFont(font)
    self.btn_login.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
    self.btn_login.setObjectName("btn_login")
    self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 340, 241, 91))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(20)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.label_3.setFont(font)
    self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
    self.input_user = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.input_user.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 300, 341, 21))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(12)
    self.input_user.setFont(font)
    self.input_user.setObjectName("input_user")
    self.input_password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.input_password.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 380, 341, 21))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(12)
    self.input_password.setFont(font)
    self.input_password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
    self.input_password.setObjectName("input_password")
    LogIn.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(LogIn)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    LogIn.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(LogIn)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(LogIn)

    #--------------------Events-------------------------------

    self.x = self.btn_login.clicked.connect(lambda:self.login_controller.logIn(self.input_user.text(),self.input_password.text(),Ui_Principal,LogIn))

    #--------------------End Events---------------------------

def retranslateUi(self, LogIn):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    LogIn.setWindowTitle(_translate("LogIn", "MainWindow"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("LogIn", "Iniciar Sesión"))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("LogIn", "Usuario:"))
    self.btn_login.setText(_translate("LogIn", "Entrar"))
    self.label_3.setText(_translate("LogIn", "Contraseña:"))
    self.input_user.setPlaceholderText(_translate("LogIn", "usuario"))
    self.input_password.setPlaceholderText(_translate("LogIn", "contraseña"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   LogIn = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
   ui = Ui_LogIn()
   ui.setupUi(LogIn)
   LogIn.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`

En el terminal ingrese este texto `pyinstaller --onefile login.py`, estuve dentro de la carpeta donde se encontraba el archivo cuando lo ejecute. También cuando ejecute no me apareció ningún error. Aquí esta los comandos que aparecieron.

```
69 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.2
69 INFO: Python: 3.9.1
69 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
70 INFO: wrote C:\Users\msi1\Downloads\-PyQt5-MySQL-CRUD-LogIn-main\Views\login.spec
73 INFO: UPX is not available.
80 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\msi1\\Downloads\\-PyQt5-MySQL-CRUD-LogIn-main\\Views',
 'C:\\Users\\msi1\\Downloads\\-PyQt5-MySQL-CRUD-LogIn-main\\Views']
160 INFO: checking Analysis
160 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
160 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
162 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
170 WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'win32ctypes.core'. Please take care they do not conflict.
173 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2756 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
2757 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib'
5225 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
5312 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
5324 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\msi1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe
5364 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\msi1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python39.dll
5382 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\msi1\Downloads\-PyQt5-MySQL-CRUD-LogIn-main\Views\login.py
5411 INFO: Processing module hooks...
5412 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5413 INFO: Excluding import of doctest from module difflib
5414 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5415 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5416 INFO: Excluding import of lib2to3.refactor from module distutils.util
5417 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5484 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5486 INFO: Excluding import of doctest from module heapq
5488 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5525 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5526 INFO: Excluding import of test from module multiprocessing.util
5526 INFO: Excluding import of test.support from module multiprocessing.util
5526 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5528 INFO: Excluding import of argparse from module pickle
5528 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from 'c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5626 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
5627 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from 'c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5689 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from 'c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5796 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py' from 'c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
6011 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
6011 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
6011 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
6062 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
6197 INFO: checking Tree
6198 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
6198 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
6251 INFO: checking Tree
6252 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
6253 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
6329 INFO: checking Tree
6329 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
6330 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
6347 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
6367 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
6369 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
6371 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
6375 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
7222 INFO: Looking for eggs
7223 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\msi1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python39.dll
7226 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
7228 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\msi1\Downloads\-PyQt5-MySQL-CRUD-LogIn-main\Views\build\login\warn-login.txt
7262 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\msi1\Downloads\-PyQt5-MySQL-CRUD-LogIn-main\Views\build\login\xref-login.html
7270 INFO: checking PYZ
7271 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
7271 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\msi1\Downloads\-PyQt5-MySQL-CRUD-LogIn-main\Views\build\login\PYZ-00.pyz
7661 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\msi1\Downloads\-PyQt5-MySQL-CRUD-LogIn-main\Views\build\login\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
7671 INFO: checking PKG
7672 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
7672 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
16432 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
16436 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\msi1\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
16436 INFO: checking EXE
16437 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
16437 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
16489 INFO: Copying icons from ['c:\\users\\msi1\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\bootloader\\images\\icon-console.ico']
16546 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 104 bytes
16546 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 3752 bytes
16547 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 2216 bytes
16549 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 1384 bytes
16550 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with 37019 bytes
16550 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 9640 bytes
16550 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 6 resource with 4264 bytes
16552 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 7 resource with 1128 bytes
16562 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\msi1\Downloads\-PyQt5-MySQL-CRUD-LogIn-main\Views\build\login\run.exe.wle0j08m
16564 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
16567 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\msi1\Downloads\-PyQt5-MySQL-CRUD-LogIn-main\Views\dist\login.exe
16703 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Esta son mis carpetas creadas, dentro de Views esta mi ventana principal de login.py

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En estos casos es también oportuno incluir el texto que se genera en la terminal durante la compilación, especialmente los errores, así como también el comando que utilizaste para lanzar la compilación cuyos parámetros pueden variar. Toma en cuenta también que muchas veces los problemas de compilación son relativos a incompatibilidad con la versión de Python que se utiliza o con las librerías del proyecto.

Comment: Normalmente no es buena idea utilizar la ultima versión de Python, porque las librerías deben actualizarse para amoldarse a la nueva versión y esto crea incompatibilidad, debido a esto suele ser mejor utilizar  una versión estable LTS (long term support).